# What does an "_" mean in Clojure language in a let binding?

Tags: clojure

for example we have function:

```
(defn my-fun [param]
      (let [[x _] param]
        x))
```

Why we use "_" in this example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(let [[x _] [1 2]] x)` destructures the first element of a sequence and binds it to the name `x`. It also binds the second value to the name `_`, but by convention this name means the value can be ignored.
Note that `(let [[x _] [1 2]] [x _])` would technically be valid Clojure, but the semantics of `_` is that we just don't care about that value. There is no special treatment of that symbol from the perspective of the compiler, just human convention.